# ModalpopupExtender not hiding, and Gridview not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender, detailsview

I have a Gridview within an UpdatePanel that shows some data from my Database.  When you click on an edit button, it opens up a detailsView within a ModalPopupextender.  When you enter in data in the textBoxes in this detailView and click "update", the Database is updated but the popup does not hide.  Then, when I close it manually by clicking "close", the  gridView does not refresh unless I refresh the page.  I was able to get this to work before, but after spending a week staring at this problem, I decided to ask you guys to see what I am doing wrong.

Here's some code! (Note: a lot of this is an adaptation of a tutorial I found)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvReservations" runat="server" CssClass="datagrid" DataKeyNames="dateSubmit"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10"
                DataSourceID="mainTable" Width="95%" OnRowUpdated="gvReservation_RowUpdated"  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GvReservations_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dateSubmit" HeaderText="Date Submitted" SortExpression="dateSubmit"
                        ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="lName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="lName" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="startTime" HeaderText="Start Time" SortExpression="startTime"
                        ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="endTime" HeaderText="End Time" SortExpression="endTime"
                        ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="labName" HeaderText="Lab" SortExpression="labName" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="class" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="term" HeaderText="Semester" SortExpression="term" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" Text="more" CommandName="Select" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="detail" Width="500px" Style="display: none;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlReservationDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
                    PopupControlID="pnlPopup" CancelControlID="btnClose"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
                <asp:DetailsView ID="dvReservationDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDetail"
                   OnDataBound="ReservationDetail_DataBound"  CssClass="detailgrid" GridLines="None" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateRows="false"
                      Visible="false" Width="100%" OnItemUpdating="ReservationDetail_Updating"   OnItemUpdated="ReservationDetail_Updated">
                    <Fields>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' ReadOnly="true" />                                    
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LabName" DataField="labName" />
                        <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="DateSubmitted" DataField="dateSubmit" />

                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Time">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="startTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("startTime") %>' />                                    
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Time">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="endTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("endTime") %>' />                                    
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />

                    </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>

                <div class="footer">

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CausesValidation="false" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

These are the events where I thought it would close the popup and update the gridView

```
protected void ReservationDetail_Updated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Page.IsValid)
        {

            //  move the data back to the data object
           // this.dvReservationDetail.UpdateItem(false);
            dvReservationDetail.Visible = false;

            //  hide the modal popup
            mdlPopup.Hide();

            //  refresh the grid

            this.gvReservations.DataBind();
            this.updatePanel.Update();
        }

    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use single update panel on page
place all controls inside it.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="detail" Width="500px" Style="display: none;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
                PopupControlID="pnlPopup" CancelControlID="btnClose"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
            <asp:DetailsView ID="dvReservationDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDetail"
               OnDataBound="ReservationDetail_DataBound"  CssClass="detailgrid" GridLines="None" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateRows="false"
                  Visible="false" Width="100%" OnItemUpdating="ReservationDetail_Updating"   OnItemUpdated="ReservationDetail_Updated">
                <Fields>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' ReadOnly="true" />                                    
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LabName" DataField="labName" />
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="DateSubmitted" DataField="dateSubmit" />

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Time">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:TextBox ID="startTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("startTime") %>' />                                    
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Time">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="endTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("endTime") %>' />                                    
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />

                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>

            <div class="footer">

                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CausesValidation="false" />
            </div>            
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Doing this made it so that the details view was not showing inside the modalpopup